# how to make sure commands in telnet is executed finished?

Tags: shell

i want to invoke telnet from shell script,and let telnet execute some commands.

and tried below script .

```
sleep 3
echo username
sleep 3
echo password
sleep 3
echo "cp a b"
sleep 5
echo exit
sleep 3
)|telnet 192.168.22.11
```

1. the problem is how can i know the command" cp a b " is finished. 5 second may not be enough.
2. if i want to use if/else or something else in telnet,how can i write the shell script?

Comment: If you are on unix, you might have available the "expect" program, it is often used for things like this.

Comment: `mkfifo in;mkfifo out;telnet <in >out;` then you can operate in a sane order without needing arbitrary sleeps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup password-less ssh

http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html

Then use ssh

```
ssh 192.168.22.11 cp a b
```

Comment: hi,amdn.  is ssh only available to linux? in AIX i don't find the ssh command.

Comment: @Venus: Here are instructions on how to install ssh for AIX:
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.security/doc/security/openssh.htm

Comment: hi,my ssh has been disabled.So for switching the User having ssh permission i need telnet.is there any work around?

Comment: @Shashank sounds like you need to talk the system administrator

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that without reading the output of telnet. You might have more luck with a tool designed to do this sort of remote running, like dsh, puppet, capistrano, or similar.